# I need make dendrogram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible create with `pgf` or something else in LaTeX a Dendrogram? 
I need something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/stats/win64/SpecifyDendrogramLeafNodeOrderExample_01.png):

[image]

I have data and need make this dendrogram graph.

Comment: How is the data formatted? Are these individual bar plots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or something else ...

Do you know R and [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A dendrogram in a \LaTeXe{} document:\par 
<<echo=F>>=
plot(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mtcars))))
@
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I absolute don't know, what is it.
How works it?

Comment: R is a standalone statistical language able too do many type of plots. In my example there are 4 nested functions to transform a clasisc dataframe example (`mtcars`)  in as tree-like structure object and plot it. Knitr is the R library able to read a mixed LaTeX+R input code (as the above `test.Rnw`)  and convert it  in a `test.tex` with LaTeX input+ R output that can be complied with `pdflatex`  as  usual, but I suggest just load the file with the Rstudio editor to convert and compile  just pushing one button. (N.B.; all of this is free software).

Answer (score 0):

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
 \usepackage[left=0.25in,right=0.25in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \leavevmode
 \psset{linecolor=black,tnsep=2pt,tnheight=0cm,treesep=.3cm,levelsep=46pt,
        radius=10pt}
 \pstree{\Tcircle{         1 }~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{ketenagakerjaan \\$\leq$   65.41    }}}{
   \Tcircle[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid]{         2 }~[tnpos=l]{        30}~{\shortstack{\texttt{1}\\0.43}}
   \Tcircle[fillcolor=green,fillstyle=solid]{         3 }~[tnpos=l]{        36}~{\shortstack{\texttt{0}\\0.14}}
  }
  \end{center}
  {A CRUISE tree. 
 The split rule is given beside each intermediate node.
 The predicted class and misclassification costs are given beneath each terminal node,
  and the number of learning samples is on its left.} 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution throw an error. Please correct/complete your code and add resulted image produced by your solution.